# Swagger Looks Empty Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, magento2.4.2, swagger, swaggerui

I had updated the Magento 2.3.5 to Magento 2.4.2 the my Swagger is not working i shows the Empty page. The console shows some error and there is a syntax error in swagger like it is showing but i had checked the code is proper in file Can anyone suggest why it is happening.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I had found this if enable these below options the swagger is not working.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same issue.

This occurs by a conflict between the javascript files the theme and the files from swagger when it are merged.

To resolve this, you should go to: **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer**

In **JavaScript Settings** change **Merge JavaScript Files** from Yes to No.

I hope that it help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass admin token in the **api_key** field.

> Generate admin token

POST : http://localurl/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=admin_user&password=admin_pass

Now add this token in api_key filed in upper right corder and apply. Check now. If still the page shown as blank then refresh the page.

Check [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/generate-local.html) for more details. Thanks!

Comment: @Rahuk Barot thanks, i had created the token already if it enter and click the apply no action are working

Comment: Did you tried to refresh the page?

Comment: Yes i tried refresh, clear all static content and di compile, i had added the third image of the error at console.

Comment: Can you check Updated post @Raghul Barot

Comment: @Sabareesh as I have checked above steps worked for me

Comment: @Sabareesh are you on multistore setup?

Comment: Check this https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9838294?key=4004a8b0d1d2a5c9dfd85f29eb633774

Comment: Yes i had cheked if i had enabled the JavaScript Bundling then i can't use the Swagger it i had set as No it is working.

Comment: Okay. If my answer is helpful to you can you please upvote?